# Why does flask app crash on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm creating a webcomic site for my friend using Heroku and Flask on Python 2.7
My code is inside this gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2b7623110479c61c87c
It works locally when I use foreman start or with the python interpreter, but when I push it to heroku, I get the Application Error page.

Heroku ps gives

```
web.1: crashed 2014/07/12 20:05:38 (~ 16m ago)
```

for no apparent reason. The project is structured as a module and since gist does not allow directories to be uploaded, I cannot do that.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do your Heroku logs say when you try to start the application?

Comment: I can't post the logs as I'm having a bad connection to heroku.com. I have to use TOR to get there. If I cold see the logs, I'd fix it myself!

Comment: no one else can see your logs... is your heroku app missing any environment variables?

Comment: Nope. It works with foreman start. Also, it does not use any env vars. It worked Perfectly for 1 hour, no commits pushed and suddnly i get this error